# Does incoming message sent to Telegram Bot contain any id of that bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

When I get update from telegram bot with user message written to bot I'd expect to see some id of bot with user id, however, I see such update:

```
Update{update_id=515450315, 
    message=Message{message_id=117, 
       from=User{id=1234567890, first_name='Name', last_name='Surname', username='null'}, 
       date=1470510167, 
       chat=Chat{id=1234567890, type=Private, first_name='Name', last_name='Surname', username='null', title='null'},
       ...
```

As a documentation says `User` is a sender of a message (user or bot). But in this case user id is actual user id (not bot id) and chat id for some reason equals to user id. So is anybody know how to get bot id during in update object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `JSON` object that bot receives telegram when user send a message to bot.( As I understand from your question)

This is completely Normal. You ask why?
For two reasons:

> 1- When `USER` send something to bot, at first `Telegram` servers grab
>   it and resend it to `bot` app on its own server. So this `JSON` object
>   contains sender (user) id logically.(why?) It is `user_id` and NOT
>   `bot_id` because `bot` receives message and should know who sent
>   it.This number(user_id) tell `bot` about sender.
>
> 2- Why `chat_id` and `user_id`(sender) are equal? Because when user is
>   in private messaging with bot ,he/she sends to bot in private chat, so
>   these two numbers are equal but when user sends something in a group
>   that your bot is its member also, there are two different numbers:
>   `chat_id` that represents `group_id` here and `user_id`(sender_id)
>   that tells to your bot who sent the message.

We can use equality check of these two numbers to find out is user in a private chat with bot or sends in a group.

And I don' see up to know that any JSON objects send from `Telegram` to `Bot` contain any field about `bot_id`. Except some specific methods like [`getMe`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme) method.(it returns basic information about the your bot)

Comment: So, am I correct that there is no way to check if a message comes from a user passing a bot or directly from a user?

Comment: @sphinks your question is unclear to me,pls explain. what is `a user passing a bot `?

Comment: I mean such situation: User writes to bot some message and the bot pass it to the backend. So as far as I understand the bot does not provide any information in message object that message has passed bo.

Comment: @sphinks , ALL messages comes from Telegram Servers to your BOT. All are initiated from a private chat or a group chat (or in soon future from channels). Bot is like a virtual user. when some one sends something to bot it is similar to he/she sends something to a friend But Bot can process and do something. I didn't hear up to know anything about passing bot or so on. [user/group...]<--->[Telegram Server]<--->[Your Bot]

Comment: Seems like I have a misleading comment:) I understand that a bot is just another user with possible auto scripts for typing responses. I was asking if bot put some uniq id, so it will possible on server side during a process of message find out that this message has come from a particular bot in case we use the same webhook for several bots and pooling update objects from several bots. As far as I understand from your answer it is impossible: we just can get an id of a user who is writing from update object.

Comment: @sphinks No. As you know you set webhook for your bot "A" with specific adress "adrs1", so all messages corressponding to bot "A" delivers at "adrs1". Now you sets bot "B" to that same "adrs1". NOW telegram removes that "adrs1" from bot "A" and dedicate it to bot "B". So bot "A" ,now, has NO delivering adress and nothing receives from BOT "A" chat window  to your scripts until you set new webhook. webhook address is unique and always is dedicated to at most ONE Bot token.

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful hint. I do not know that there is no way to bind several bots to the same webhook.

Comment: @sphinks, I should mention that you can send from one script to many bots by their tokens (tokens are a part of sent message to telegram servers as you know)  but just can receive at most as one bot (as I  mentioned above)

Comment: Thanks, about sending I have already do it so, but I faced a problem with receiving. Now it is clear why. :)

Comment: @TickTock, are you somehow from Telegram Bot development command? The thing is, that I can currently set same webhook (same adrs1) as a callback for both bot A and not B (and presumably bot C). This way I receive updates from both bots to the very same webhook. In this case it would be convenient if the incoming data would contain any sort of bot_id so message can be dispatched.

Comment: By the way, the above seems more or less expected behaviour, as why bot A would become "unhooked" when I set same webhook to bot B -> there is no notice on it and no expectation that would happen